# How do I write back results of a count query to a column in R?

Tags: r

I would like to count the instances of a Employee ID in a column and write back the results to a new column in my dataframe. So far I am able to count the instances and display the results in the R Studio console, but I'm not sure how to write the results back. Here is what I have tested successfully:

```
ids<-BAR$`Employee ID`
counts<-data.frame(table(ids))
counts
```

And here are the returned results:

```
1   00000018    1
2   00000179    1
3   00001045    1
4   00002729    1
5   00003095    2
6   00003100    1
```

Thanks!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making a reproducible example. Is the question just how to assign a vector or something else to a data frame? Write the results back to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to create a column, use `add_count`

```
library(dplyr)
BAR1 <- BAR %>%
          add_count(`Employee ID`)
```

---

`table` returns the summarised output.  If we want to create a column in the original data

```
BAR1$n <- table(ids)[as.character(BAR$`Employee ID`)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use a data.table you will be able to do this quickly, especially with larger datasets, using `.N` to count number of occurrences per grouping variable given in `by`.

```
# Load data.table 
library(data.table)
# Convert data to a data.table 
setDT(BAR)
# Count and assign counts per level of ID
BAR[, count := .N, by = ID]
```